# CouchDB Views - emit Keys as JSON & filter based on any attribute

Tags: couchdb

Consider following Employee document structure

```
{ 
   "_id":...,
   "rev":...,
   "type":"Employee",
   "fName":...,
   "lName":...,
   "designation":...,
   "department":...,
   "reportingTo":...,
   "isActive":..,
   more attributes
   more attributes
}
```

And following map function in a View named "Employee"

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.type=="Employee") {
    emit({
            "EID":doc._id,
            "FirstName":doc.fName,
            "LastName":doc.lName,
            "Designation":doc.designation,
            "Department":doc.department,
            "ReportingTo":doc.reportingTo,
            "Active":doc.isActive
         },
        null
        );
  }
};
```

I want to query this view based on any combination & order of emitted attributes ( a query may include few random attributes may be like duck typing ). Is it possible? If so kindly let me know some samples or links.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same problem a few times; you can, but you'll have to index each by itself (not all in one hash like you've done). But you could through the whole thing in the value for emit. It can be fairly inefficient, but gets the job done. (See this link: [View Snippets](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_Snippets#Arbitrarily_query_against_any_document_property_.28.22uniview.22.29))

I.e.:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type=="Employee") {
        emit(["EID",doc.values.EID], doc.values);
        emit(["FirstName", doc.fName], doc.values);
        emit(["LastName", doc.lName], doc.values);
        emit(["Designation", doc.designation], doc.values);
        emit(["Department", doc.department], doc.values);
        emit(["ReportingTo", doc.reportingTo], doc.values);
        emit(["Active", doc.isActive], doc.values);
    }
}
```

This puts all "EID" things in the same part of the tree, etc., I'm not sure if that is good or bad for you.

If you start needing a lot of functionality with [field name:]value searches, its probably worth it to move towards a Lucene-CouchDB setup. Several exist, but are a little immature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The link you provided taught me some new ideas. 
But your solution does not solve my problem . I want to query based on many random attributes. But your solution allows me to query based on any 1 attribute.